# Need help on scrollview and orientation

Tags: android

I added a scrollview to `main.xml` but in AVD emulator when I was trying to type something in the editText, the softkeyboard was only showing partially.

1. How can I give main.xml scrolling ability?
2. Also I would like to keep the screen orientation as portrait. In main.xml, I am using `android:orientation = "vertical"`.

Is there anything else I need to be doing to keep my app in portrait mode?

Comment: add some code or screenshot to help us to see whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

"I would like to keep the screen orientation as portrait"

If you want to keep the screen from rotating, you will need to modify your Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make the page scrollable in android? Any ideas.